# Send DXY-GL command to printer

Tags: printing

How to send DXY-GL commands to a plotter? My plotter can draw only lines. Can I send text commands via stty to the printer port?

Comment: Does this package help? http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/hpgl2ps.html

Comment: I think it does the reverse thing.

Comment: `stty` is a command, not a device.  anyway, your question is unclear.  do you wish to send DXY-GL data to your plotter?

Comment: not data but commands. Think of `cat file_with_commands > /dev/tty`.